# Alternative for push_back or how to speed up a vector of 2d array

Tags: c++, performance

I have a code like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
int main()
{
    using Array2d4 = std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 4>;
    using Array2d3 = std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3>;
    Array2d4 B;
    B.fill({});
    std::vector<Array2d3> B1;
    Array2d3 T1;
    //B1.reserve(400000);
    auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            T1[0][0] = B[j][0];
            T1[0][1] = 0;
            T1[1][0] = 0;
            T1[1][1] = B[j][1];
            T1[2][0] = B[j][0];
            T1[2][1] = B[j][1];
            B1.push_back(T1);
        }
    }
    auto finish1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed1 = finish1 - start1;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed1.count() << " s\n";
}
```

My gut feeling is slow as the elapsed time shows:

```
Elapsed time: 0.020
```

I learned that it should be faster if you preallocate before using push_back, however even when I use the reserve function (commented in the code):

```
Elapsed time: 0.018
```

This is still not fast enough. Any way to speed it up? It is also acceptable to change the structure.

Comment: It appears you are pushing the same value into `B1` 400000 times.  Is that intentional?  If so, you could probably use `std::resize()` with two arguments to do that for you; whether it would be faster or not I don't know.

Comment: The body of the loop doesn't depend on `i` or `j`. Just set up `T1` once, then push 400,000 copies of it into the vector at once, e.g. with `B1.resize(400000, T1)`

Comment: You probably just forgot to turn on optimizations when you compiled the code. With `reserve` uncommented, I get 0.072 with optimizations disabled but 0.0068 with optimizations enabled.

Comment: When you `push_back` you have to copy the object. In case of `array` it is an expensive operation. You may cut this expense working inplace in the vector.

Comment: I am using Visual Stuido, the only thing I know about optimization is about running in release mode.

Comment: It depends on j, I have a typo, sorry.

Comment: If it doesn't depend on `i`, the comment of @IgorTandetnik is still relevant.

Comment: The outer loop is intentional, just for testing.

Comment: "_It is still not fast enough_" - What would be fast enough?

Comment: Arrays can't be moved around, only copied. It's possible that you can get away with putting something other than the actual arrays in there. For example, a vector of spans that refer to one big backing storage. Maybe even a vector of vectors with a cache-friendly allocator.

Comment: Would [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vYEajqWaj) be fast enough? (note: the time it takes to allocate the vector isn't counted - just like you didn't count the  time it takes to `reserve`)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Note that the compiler optimizes everything (but a small loop) away unless you make some use of B1 after the loop (since it's allowed to discard useless side effects).

Comment: @Hasturkun Yeah, OP will have to test it in his app to say if it's fast enough or not. [This](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sWzxKrTce) may give a more correct time than my previous example. It's still 10 times faster than what OP reported.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code with and without reserve:

```
Best of 3 without resreve: Elapsed time: 0.0218509 s
Best of 3 with reserve: Elapsed time: 0.00879622 s
```

As far as I see it gets roughly twice as fast, which kind of makes sense considering that push_back increases the capacity to 1.5 times the previous one in case the allocated memory is not sufficient. [image: formula], therefore there are rouglhy 31 unnecessary copies without reserve.

All in all this means that roughly [image: formula] unnecessary copies are made of double arrays.

While your original code is doing 400000*6=2400000 assignments to double values. If the array copies were only copies of the contained 2 double values, than it would add up to roughly 172000 double value copies so at least they seem to be in the same magnitude according to this approximation.

Also keep in mind that my approximation regarding the necessary numbers of allocations without using reserve is underestimating the required re-allocations since capacity is always an integer so when the reallocation happens, only int(capacity * 1.5) memory gets allocated which is less or equal to capacity * 1.5.

Have you recompiled the code before running the tests?